# Leitura de números inteiros e negativos em phyton

Tags: python-3.x

Sou novata em Phyton e não sei criar todo o código exigido no enunciado. 
Segue enunciado:
Leia números inteiros do teclado até que um número negativo seja teclado. Escreva, caso existam, quais os cinco maiores números lidos. Caso menos que cinco números sejam lidos, mostre todos os números lidos. 
Restrição Não é permitido manter em memória mais que seis números lidos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para ler um inteiro em python:

```
x = int(input("Enter a number: "))
```

Para fazer um loop até que uma condição seja atinginda:

```
while (<expressão_condicional>):
    <código_executado>
```

Um exemplo:

```
count = 0
while (count < 9):
   print 'The count is:', count
   count = count + 1
```

Agora, quanto à lógica da questão proposta, é bem simples. Sugiro que tentes resolver com as informações que te passei. Afinal, se eu postasse aqui, tu não poderias copiar e usar no teu trabalho da faculdade, pois seria **plágio**.

Comment: Agradeço a ajuda até aqui. Eu estou precisando é desse norte, ver o que estou acertando e o que estou errando. Obrigada mesmo.